# What is the purpose of using Object argument when defining a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, object

For class definitions in Python,  class Name(object) gets an argument of Object. On below code, I tried to use the class without having this argument "Object" and the code still works fine.

What is the purpose of having the object there? Does this have a special meaning in Python just like **init** does?

```
class Vector(object):
def __init__(self, coordinates):
    try:
        if not coordinates:
            raise ValueError
        self.coordinates = tuple(coordinates)
        self.dimension = len(coordinates)

    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('The coordinates must be nonempty')

    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')


def __str__(self):
    return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)


def __eq__(self, v):
    return self.coordinates == v.coordinates
```

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Comment: Okay so I asked a question that was already out there. We use this to inherit object class when creating new objects.